# ASP.NET page load twice when using url rewriting

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I have an asp.net page with url rewriting rule. The rule shows below:

```
 <rule name="DiscoverCategorySEO">
      <match url="^Discover/([0-9]+)/"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.axd$"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="News/Discover.aspx?Section={R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>
```

I put a break point in the Page_Load method for debugging. Then I found when I visit 'http://[domain]/Discover/1/'. The discover page will load twice. However, if I put 'http://[domain]/News/Discover.aspx?Section=1", the break point will only be hit once.

Does anyone know how can I keep url rewriting rule and meanwhile load page only once?

Comment: looks like you need to say stopprocessing=true

Comment: Hi Bearded Llama, where do I add this?

Comment: it's an attribute in there somewhere... try the action element... intellisense will guide you ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<rule name="DiscoverCategorySEO"  enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^Discover/([0-9]+)/"/>
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.axd$"/>
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}"  pattern="^Discover/([0-9]+)/"  />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="News/Discover.aspx?Section={R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks for your reply. I tried the code u gave. But it still hit the break point twice.

Comment: did you reset the iis ?

Comment: hi i have adjust the answer is this ok for you?

Comment: Hi Joseph, I changed to those code and met 404 error.